# How to get json data that has same key javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have data of class and its sentence ( training data ), how can i convert this json data

```
[
  { class: 'Reservation', sentence: 'make reservation' },
  { class: 'Reservation', sentence: 'do reservation' },
  { class: 'Greetings', sentence: 'Hello' },
  { class: 'Greetings', sentence: 'Good Morning' }
]
```

into this format data :

```
[
  { class: 'Reservation', sentence: ['make reservation','do reservation'] },
  { class: 'Greetings', sentence: ['Hello','Good Morning'] }
]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything already?

Comment: Show us your failed code. Hint: you just need to group them on `class`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through each object and add them to a new array. Before adding check if the object already in the new array, if it is, instead of adding you can push current sentence to existing object.

Steps

1. Create an empty array
2. Loop though array of the objects (not the new array, your original object array)
3. Check if object with class value already exists
4. If No, push a new object to the new array, where value of class is your class, and value of sentence is an array with sentence being the first item  (refer to the code below). If Yes, push current sentence to the existing object's sentence array.

```js
var data = [
  { class: 'Reservation', sentence: 'make reservation' },
  { class: 'Reservation', sentence: 'do reservation' },
  { class: 'Greetings', sentence: 'Hello' },
  { class: 'Greetings', sentence: 'Good Morning' }
]

var dataFormatted = [];

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    //document.write(JSON.stringify(data[i]));
  const existingClass = dataFormatted.find(d => d.class == data[i].class);
  if(existingClass){
    existingClass.sentence.push(data[i].sentence)
  } else{
    dataFormatted.push({
        class: data[i].class,
      sentence: [data[i].sentence]
    });
  }
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(dataFormatted))
```

Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can look through the json array and assign a new array by attempting to append to the sentences list or creating a new item if there was not an existing result found:

```js
const json = [
  { class: 'Reservation', sentence: 'make reservation' },
  { class: 'Reservation', sentence: 'do reservation' },
  { class: 'Greetings', sentence: 'Hello' },
  { class: 'Greetings', sentence: 'Good Morning' }
]

const data = []
json.forEach((item) => {
  let found = data.find(e => e.class === item.class);
  if (found) {
    found.sentence.push(item.sentence);
  } else {
    data.push({
      class: item.class,
      sentence: [item.sentence]
    });
  }
})


console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to `consolidate` like:

```js
function consolidate(array){
  const r = [];
  for(let i=0,o,p,l=array.length; i<l; i++){
    o = array[i]; p = r.find(d=>d.class === o.class);
    if(p){
      p.sentence.push(o.sentence);
    }
    else{
      r.push({class:o.class, sentence:[o.sentence]}); 
    }
  }
  return r;
}
const testArray = [
  { class: 'Reservation', sentence: 'make reservation' },
  { class: 'Reservation', sentence: 'do reservation' },
  { class: 'Greetings', sentence: 'Hello' },
  { class: 'Greetings', sentence: 'Good Morning' }
];
console.log(consolidate(testArray));
```